# expressjs controller routing issue

Tags: typescript, express

I have a simple ExpressJS app that I have an issue with, I cannot get extended routes to be recognised, an example can be found below.

INITIALISATION

```
var app = express();
app.use("/cars", carRouter);
```

ROUTER

```
let carRouter = Router();
carRouter.get("/", carController.all);
carRouter.get("/:id", carController.one);
carRouter.get("/:id/state", carController.state);
```

in my controller, I am linking up to a MongoDB using the Mongoose library.

CONTROLLER

```
// Car is imported as a Mongoose Schema

export let all = (request: Request, response: Response): void => {
    Car.find().then((data) => {
        response.status(200).json({ data });
    }).catch((error) => {
        response.status(500).json({ error });
    });
};

export let one = (request: Request, response: Response): void => {
    Car.find(request.params.id).then((data) => {
        response.status(200).json({ data });
     }).catch((error) => {
        response.status(500).json({ error });
    });
};

export let state = (request: Request, response: Response): void => {
    Car.find(request.params.id).then((data) => {
        response.status(200).json({ data });
    }).catch((error) => {
        response.status(500).json({ error });
    });
};
```

I am not able to make the `/:id/state` call work. It does not call the specified `state` callback of the `carController`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the mongoose query not being correctly set up. I should have used the following:

```
let id = request.params.id;
let query = Car.where({ "_id": id});
query.findOne().then((data) => {
    response.status(200).json(data);
}).catch((error) => {
    // do something with error
});
```